# Visual not connected exception when Items.Clear()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik-radribbonbar

I've an issue in my application. I don't think the component is the cause but I use the RadRibbonView of Telerik components.

I need to rebuild my ribbon in my application. So I clear all items of the ribbon, then I re-add new items.

This is what I do for clearing the ribbon:

```
var tabs = this.ribbon.Items.Cast<RadRibbonTab>();
var groups = tabs.SelectMany(t => t.Items.Cast<RadRibbonGroup>());
// Clear controls in groups
groups.ToList().ForEach(g => g.Items.Clear());
// Clear groups in tabs
tabs.ToList().ForEach(t => t.Items.Clear());
// Clear tabs
this.ribbon.Items.Clear();
```

This works well. But sometimes I have the exception "This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource" on the `this.ribbon.Items.Clear();` line.

Why is it do this?
Can I prevent it?

Comment: did you see the stack trace if there is anything interesting? Does application crash or close after exception?

Comment: Nothing interesting in the stacktrace... And yes, application crash after exception.

Comment: ok, seems like component issue. perhaps Telerik component forums maybe a good source for finding a solution. I tried to search google too but no relevant information found.

Comment: I just find that is the this.ribbon which has no visual sometimes. But I don't know why...

Comment: could you share a working sample of your app which can reproduce the same issue? May I have a look here.

Comment: I just finish to write the sample and... It works well... The problem must be due to another part of my code. I'll look. 
Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: That's great! BTW You might check if there are some event handlers needs to be detached or there are some active references deep inside the object. event handlers may cause such issues as they can keep the references alive, they are well known for memory leak issues.

Comment: @floc post the full exception text, not just parts of the message. The full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()` contains the actual location where the exception was thrown, any inner exceptions and a stack trace with all the methods called leading to the one that raised the exception. This will help you find out which part of the code threw, which method etc